# How to update a pandas dataframe, from multiple API calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, json-normalize

I need to do a python script to

1. Read a csv file with the columns (`person_id`, `name`, `flag`). The file has 3000 rows.
2. Based on the `person_id` from the csv file, I need to call a URL passing the `person_id` to do a GET
   http://api.myendpoint.intranet/get-data/1234
   The URL will return some information of the `person_id`, like example below. I need to get all rents objects and save on my csv. My output needs to be like this

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

ids = pd.read_csv(f"{path}/data.csv", delimiter=';')
person_rents = df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=list('person_id','carId','price','rentStatus'))

for id in ids:
    response = request.get(f'endpoint/{id["person_id"]}')
    json = response.json()
    person_rents.append( [person_id, rent['carId'], rent['price'], rent['rentStatus'] ] )
    pd.read_csv(f"{path}/data.csv", delimiter=';' )
```

```
person_id;name;flag;cardId;price;rentStatus
1000;Joseph;1;6638;1000;active
1000;Joseph;1;5566;2000;active
```

Response example

```
{
    "active": false,
    "ctodx": false,
    "rents": [{
            "carId": 6638,
            "price": 1000,
            "rentStatus": "active"
        }, {
            "carId": 5566,
            "price": 2000,
            "rentStatus": "active"
        }
    ],
    "responseCode": "OK",
    "status": [{
            "request": 345,
            "requestStatus": "F"
        }, {
            "requestId": 678,
            "requestStatus": "P"
        }
    ],
    "transaction": false
}
```

3. After save the additional data from response on csv, i need to get data from another endpoint using the carId on the URL. The mileage result must be save in the same csv.
   http://api.myendpoint.intranet/get-mileage/6638
   http://api.myendpoint.intranet/get-mileage/5566

The return for each call will be like this

```
{"mileage":1000.0000}
{"mileage":550.0000}
```

The final output must be

```
person_id;name;flag;cardId;price;rentStatus;mileage
1000;Joseph;1;6638;1000;active;1000.0000
1000;Joseph;1;5566;2000;active;550.0000
```

SOmeone can help me with this script?
Could be with pandas or any python 3 lib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Code Explanation

- Create dataframe, `df`, with `pd.read_csv`.

  - It is expected that all of the values in `'person_id'`, are unique.
- Use `.apply` on `'person_id'`, to call `prepare_data`.

  - `prepare_data` expects `'person_id'` to be a `str` or `int`, as indicated by the type annotation, `Union[int, str]`
- Call the `API`, which will return a `dict`, to the `prepare_data` function.
- Convert the `'rents'` key, of the `dict`, into a dataframe, with `pd.json_normalize`.
- Use `.apply` on `'carId'`, to call the `API`, and extract the `'mileage'`, which is added to dataframe `data`, as a column.
- Add `'person_id'` to `data`, which can be used to merge `df` with `s`.
- Convert `pd.Series`, `s` to a dataframe, with `pd.concat`, and then `merge` `df` and `s`, on `person_id`.
- Save to a csv with `pd.to_csv` in the desired form.

#### Potential Issues

- If there's an issue, it's most likely to occur in the `call_api` function.
- As long as `call_api` returns a `dict`, like the response shown in the question, the remainder of the code will work correctly to produce the desired output.

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from typing import Union

def call_api(url: str) -> dict:
    r = requests.get(url)
    return r.json()

def prepare_data(uid: Union[int, str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    
    d_url = f'http://api.myendpoint.intranet/get-data/{uid}'
    m_url = 'http://api.myendpoint.intranet/get-mileage/'
    
    # get the rent data from the api call
    rents = call_api(d_url)['rents']
    # normalize rents into a dataframe
    data = pd.json_normalize(rents)
    
    # get the mileage data from the api call and add it to data as a column
    data['mileage'] = data.carId.apply(lambda cid: call_api(f'{m_url}{cid}')['mileage'])
    # add person_id as a column to data, which will be used to merge data to df
    data['person_id'] = uid
    
    return data
    

# read data from file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')

# call prepare_data
s = df.person_id.apply(prepare_data)

# s is a Series of DataFrames, which can be combined with pd.concat
s = pd.concat([v for v in s])

# join df with s, on person_id
df = df.merge(s, on='person_id')

# save to csv
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

- If there are any errors when running this code:

  1. Leave a comment, to let me know.
  2. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64127158/edit) your question, and paste the entire `TraceBack`, as text, into a code block.

### Example

```py
# given the following start dataframe
   person_id    name  flag
0       1000  Joseph     1
1        400     Sam     1

# resulting dataframe using the same data for both id 1000 and 400
   person_id    name  flag  carId  price rentStatus  mileage
0       1000  Joseph     1   6638   1000     active   1000.0
1       1000  Joseph     1   5566   2000     active   1000.0
2        400     Sam     1   6638   1000     active   1000.0
3        400     Sam     1   5566   2000     active   1000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to implement this. One of them would be, like you started in your comment:

- read the CSV file with pandas
- for each line take the person_id and build a call
- the delivered JSON response can then be taken from the rents
- the carId is then extracted for each individual rental
- finally this is collected in a row_list
- the row_list is then converted back to csv via pandas

A very simple solution without any error handling could look something like this:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

path = '/some/path/'
df = pd.read_csv(f'{path}/data.csv', delimiter=';')

rows_list = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    rentCall = f'http://api.myendpoint.intranet/get-data/{row.person_id}'
    print(rentCall)
    response = requests.get(rentCall)
    r = json.loads(response.text, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
    for rent in r.rents:
        mileageCall = f'http://api.myendpoint.intranet/get-mileage/{rent.carId}'
        print(mileageCall)
        response2 = requests.get(mileageCall)
        m = json.loads(response2.text, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
        state = "active" if r.active else "inactive"
        rows_list.append((row['person_id'], row['name'], row['flag'], rent.carId, rent.price, state, m.mileage))
df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=('person_id', 'name', 'flag', 'carId', 'price', 'rentStatus', 'mileage'))
print(df.to_csv(index=False, sep=';'))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Speeding up with multiprocessing

You mention that you have 3000 rows, which means that you'll have to make a lot of API calls. Depending on the connection, every one of these calls might take a while. As a result, performing this in a sequential way might be too slow. The majority of the time, your program will just be waiting on a response from the server without doing anything else.
We can improve this performance by using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html).

I use all the code from [Trenton his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64179359/9726179), but I replace the following sequential call:

```py
# call prepare_data
s = df.person_id.apply(prepare_data)
```

With a parallel alternative:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
n_processes=20  # Experiment with this to see what works well
with Pool(n_processes) as p:
  s=p.map(prepare_data, df.person_id)
```

Alternatively, a threadpool might be faster, but you'll have to test that by replacing the import with
`from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool`.